# RecurrenceData Xml to Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence converter

Tags: calendar, recurring-events

I want to generate EWS Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence object based on RecurrenceData column of SharePoint List.

SharePoint stores recurring information in Xml format in RecurrenceData column whereas EWS uses own Recurrence object to hold recurring information:

```
?item["RecurrenceData"]
"<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><weekly tu=\"TRUE\" weekFrequency=\"1\" /></repeat><repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever></rule></recurrence>"
```

I am wondering if someone has any code snippet or pointer to any article which provide XML parsing of RecurrenceData and create required Recurrence object. Look like it will require some brute force method to parse RecurrenceData.

Comment: I have the same requirements, but can not find a solution as well. Do you have any news about that?

Comment: Mikhail, I didn't find any solution to convert Xml to Reference object, so I build my own. It's just a simple parser which pull out data from Xml node and fill respective fields of the Reference object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Firoz. Several hours ago I gave up googling for the solution and decided to use the same approach too.